# Help on Integral Divergence Proof

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Question: Prove that $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\log^n(x)} \,dx$ diverges for all real numbers $n$.

My Work so far:

First, we substitute $u = \log x$ and $du = \frac{1}{x}\, dx,$ giving us
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^n} \,du,$$ since $\log(1) = 0.$
Subbing in $b$ for $\infty,$ we instead get $$\lim_{b\to \infty}\int_0^b \frac{1}{u^n} \,du.$$
Taking the integral, we get $$\lim_{b\to \infty} \frac{\log^{1-n}(x)}{1-n} + C \Big|_1^b.$$
For $n<1,$ $$ \lim_{b\to \infty} (\frac{\log^{1-n}(b)}{1-n} - \lim_{a \to 1^{+}} \frac{\log^{1-n}(a)}{1-n}) = \frac{\infty}{1-n}\,  -\,  0 = \infty.$$
For $n>1,$ $$\lim_{b\to \infty} (\frac{\log^{1-n}(b)}{1-n} - \lim_{a \to 1^{+}} \frac{\log^{1-n}(a)}{1-n}) = 0\,  -\,  \frac{1}{0(1-n)} = -\infty.$$
Finally, for $n=1,$ we get $$\lim_{b\to \infty} \int_0^{b} \frac{1}{u}\, du = \lim_{b\to \infty} \log u\Big|_0^b=\infty-(-\infty)=\infty.$$
Therefore, for all real numbers $n,$ $$ \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\log^n(x)} \,dx$$ diverges.

Comment: Note that $\log 1=0$, so the lower limit in the integration is not $1$ anymore

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Yes. That's how it should look

Comment: $x = \mathrm{e}^{t}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the change of variable you proposed,$$I=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x\log^n(x)} dx=\int_0^\infty u^{-n} du$$
If $n\ne 1$, $$I=\frac{u^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\Big|_0^\infty$$
Depending on $n$, either the upper limit or lower limit is infinite.
For $n=1$, $$I=\ln u\Big|_0^\infty=\infty-(-\infty)=\infty$$

Comment: Why are we able to make the lower limit equal to 0?

Comment: Because you changed the variable. Lower limit for the $u$ integral $\log(1)=0$

Comment: But the problem is that plugging in 1 for x or 0 for u makes the integral undefined.

Comment: Not true. Take $n=-2$ then you have $\int_0^\infty u^{-(-2)} du=\frac{u^3}3\Big|_0^\infty=\infty-0=\infty$

Comment: What happens if n is positive, making u be on the denominator? You can't divide by 0 so how would that work?

Comment: Correct. It's the limit when $u\to 0$. The fact that the limit is infinite means that the integral is divergent. And that's what you were asked to prove.

Comment: Is my edited version better?